# Install R 'sf' package on Centos -- gdal shared library error

Tags: r, linux

How can I install the R `'sf'` package on CentOS? On attempting to install, I initially got an error due to an out of date gdal package; I updated gdal (built from source following: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix) and now have an error:

```
 checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... yes
 checking GDAL: /usr/local/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
 checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ.4 is available for linking:... yes
 checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ.4 is available fur running:... 
 ./gdal_proj: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.20: cannot open 
 shared object file: No such file or directory
  no
 configure: error: OGRCoordinateTransformation() does not return a 
coord.trans: 
 PROJ.4 not available?
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
```

I've tried creating a symlink to `libgdal.so.20`, but this doesn't change the error at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add `/usr/local/lib` to e.g. `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgdal-x86_64.conf`
2. Run ldconfig
3. Restart R
4. Try again

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the ldconfig step!

Comment: If the file does not exist, feel free to create it.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave has given exact steps & Please follow the below steps with some more explanation.

1. Add `/usr/local/lib` to e.g. `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgdal-x86_64.conf` Please create the file **libgdal-x86_64.conf** if doesn't exists.

`#echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libgdal-x86_64.conf`

2. Run ldconfig

`#ldconfig`

3. Make sure you have `GEOS,GDAL,PROJ` installed on your system.

`#yum install  proj.x86_64 proj-devel.x86_64 proj-epsg.x86_64 proj-nad.x86_64 geos*`

Try again

4. Go to R cli & hit 
   `install.packages("sf")`

Thanks hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me! But I trying to install sf in Ubuntu OS. If you could help me here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67133013/4300670

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has a multi-user/multi-computer environment with the need to have multiple versions of various pieces of software installed, I fixed my issue with:

```
install.packages('sf',configure.args='--with-gdal-config=/sw/gdal/2.2.3-gcc4/bin/gdal-config --with-proj-include=/sw/proj/4.9.3-gcc4/include --with-proj-lib=/sw/proj/4.9.3-gcc4/lib --with-proj-share=/sw/proj/4.9.3-gcc4/share/proj')
```

Obviously you may/would have to alter path names from what I have.

Comment: could you please explain how to find the relative arguments ?